# python function not working properly it doesn't return the values that user should be getting

Tags: python

```
def divisors(n):
    ans =0
    for i in range(n):
        i += 1
        k=n%i
        if k!=1:
            ans=i
    return ans
print(20)
```

I have a function that's not working properly when I run it prints the `n` value instead of printing out the divisors.

Comment: What is the result you want?

Comment: so it should be printing out the divisors for 20 which would be 1,2,4,5,10,20

Comment: The code has not called the def() function. It prints "20" just like you told it to. You might try `print(divisors(20))`, but that will only print the last `ans` value since `divisors()` does not return a list.

Comment: @AndreL I've rolled back the edit you made for a couple of reasons. The first and biggest was that your change to the code invalidated part of a legitimate answer and was not based on comments provided by the OP. If the code does not do what the OP claims it does, you may inadvertently *hide the problem* by making those sorts of changes to the code. Additionally, the other changes you made did not improve the post. It moved some text to a different place, but there were clear, obvious, low effort to fix grammatical and mechanical changes you could have made.

Answer (score 8):

Three key issues are:

1. `k=n%i` returns the remainder - if the remainder != 1 it doesn't mean that `i` is a divisor!
2. in the for-loop you keep overriding `ans` and at the end of the function you return the value that was found on the last iteration that satisfied the `if` condition. What you want to do instead is to accumulate all the `ans`s into a list and return that list.
3. The `print` at the end is not calling the function - it simply prints the number 20.

I'm not posting a corrected solution because I think that it will be a good exercise for you to fix these bugs by yourself, good luck!

Comment: def divisors(n):
    ans = []
    for i in range(n):
        i += 1
        if n % i == 0:
            ans.append(i)
    return ans

Comment: @user4574134 you got it :)

Comment: def divisors(n):
    ans = []
    for i in range(n):
        i += 1
        if n % i == 0:
            ans.append(i)
    return ans
print(divisors([30]))     this is not working when i enter 30 as a list  value

Comment: @user4574134 the function receives an integer as an argument, why would you pass a list ?

Answer (score 3):

I saved the result in a list:

```
def divisors(n):
    ans = []
    for i in range(n):
        i += 1
        k=n%i
        if k==0:
            ans.append(i)
    return ans

print divisors(20)
```

Comment: You missed something when cleaning your code. The function should `return ans`.

Answer (score 2):

If you what a more elegant way you can use `lists-comprehension`, also you reduce it in one line.

```
def divisors(n):
    return [i+1 for i in range(n) if n%(i+1) == 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use generator function with `yield` for that purpose:

```
def divisors(n):
    iterable = xrange(1, n + 1)
    for i in iterable:
        k = n % i
        if k == 0:
            ans = i
            yield ans

print list(divisors(20))
```

Comment: i think that is an advanced approach for the OP level, but its a good answer indeed.